# Screensaver that just disables keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Does anyone know of a way that I can lock my computer without a screensaver being shown?

I run some graphs that I like to check every now and then from a distance. But I don't want other people to have access to the computer.

I would love if there was a way to basically disable the keyboard and mouse - or activate the locked screen once any mouse or keyboard activity is detected and require a login.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Do you want to see the graphs once the lock is on? Windows Key + L will lock your PC and will require the login credentials but it will  display whatever is the default Windows setting for that instance.

Comment: Yes I want to see the graphs while the lock is on. They update every few seconds - it's similar to watching stocks.

Comment: I suppose I could write a script to trigger windows key + L whenever mouse or keyboard action is detected. Would VBscript be best for this? My windows scripting days are long forgotten.

Comment: I think PowerShell will work better. I will try looking into that.

Comment: You might want to check this [one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Lock-screen-apps-sample-9843dc3a) out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that program called [Clear Lock](http://joshstine.wordpress.com/tag/windows-7-lock-screen-app/) will do the trick if you're using one monitor.

> The Windows+L shortcut is a handy for quickly password-protecting your machine, but if you want to lock it while keeping an eye on your desktop, ClearLock will lock your desktop with a transparent layer so you can see what’s going on.

And it can be downloaded from [here](http://www.swanrivercomputers.com/programs/clearlock/)

If you don't want to run an exe file then you should check some code samples at [Lock Screen Apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Lock-screen-apps-sample-9843dc3a) (by Microsoft). One caveat though, it's meant for Windows 8.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping to not have to run an .exe... I should have specified that earlier